# Multitenant DB connection problem with Oracle TLS 1.2 Diffie-Hellman

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, database-connection, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm trying to understand where is the problem of a connection issue I'm having. Recently I've built a Java system with multitenant database connection with plain communication (unsecure). As part of the development I need to upgrade the connection to a more secure communication because the system will link databases on demand over the internet.

For this case I'm working with two Oracle databases 19c both hosted on remote servers, lets call them OServerA and OServerB which are configured to use TLS 1.2.

So as a fast idea of what goes on, this JavaPlatform connects to OServerA, OServerB, ..., OserverN indistinctly dynamicly and not bound to any datasource application.yml static definition.

From OServerA I can reach OServerB because I did an exchanged of self-signed certificates between them. Prove of that connection success is that I can make TNSPING successfully, and logon through SQLPlus, that's the expected result. Also if I connect remotely to OserverB I can query the network protocol and I get "tcps" so it looks good enough.

[SQLPlus connection from OServerA to OServerB with network protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8TE.png)

So this is at, lets call it DB level.

Problems came with the multitenant connection... because it looses all sense to exchange certificates on-demand database connections, I'm looking for a relative fast easy-to-use change of db connection so make that exchange of certificates is not what I'm looking for. Between the extensive Oracle's doc it seems to me that the Diffie-Hellman method could fit into my solution. So, I prepared the configurations, change the way I connect with jdbc thin driver from "JDBC url" to "Descriptor url" and... my java platform never connected anymore.

The multitenant connection works neat over plain communication, port 1521 with "jdbc url", but when I modify the connection logic to "Descriptor url", port 2484 and set the cipher suites as a property of this datasources I get a Connection Timeout as the application tries to connect to OServerA or OServerB and everything fails.

Next I add some configuration info from OServerA

SQLNET.ora

```
SQLNET.CIPHER_SUITE= (SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
SSL_VERSION=1.2

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

WALLET_LOCATION = 
    (SOURCE = 
      (METHOD = FILE)
      (METHOD_DATA =
        (DIRECTORY = C:\Oracle\db_home\wallet) 
      )
    )
```

LISTENER.ora

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\Oracle\db_home\log

WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = C:\Oracle\db_home\wallet)
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = MAGIC)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\db_home)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = MAGIC)
    )
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = DESKTOP-6B0213U)(PORT = 2484))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-6B0213U)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

TNSNAMES.ora

```
MAGIC_SSL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = DESKTOP-6B0213U)(PORT = 2484))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MAGIC)
    )
  )

RMT_XE_SSL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = OServerB)(PORT = 2484))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

As you can see, the definition inside tnsnames.ora MAGIC_SSL allows to connect to OServerA and RMT_XE_SSL allows to connect from OServerA to OServerB with TCPS as I described before.

And finally this is how the "Descriptor url" looks to use inside HikariDataSource to connect from the JavaPlatform to OServerA or OServerB (OServerA in this example):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=OserverA)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MAGIC)))
```

As I said, multitenant works well without tcps and the only modification I made on my datasource configuration was changing the "jdbc url" to "descriptor url" and add the "oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites" corresponding to Diffie-Hellman to the data source:

```
      HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
      hikariConfig.setUsername(dbSettings.getUserName());
      hikariConfig.setPassword(dbSettings.getPassword());
      hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dbSettings.JDBConnectionURL());
      hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
      hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(Long.parseLong(maxLifeTimeMs));
      Properties dsProperties = new Properties();
      dsProperties.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites", "(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)");
      hikariConfig.setDataSourceProperties(dsProperties);
      HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
```

As per java log output, not much to say... just a poor Connection Timeout

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'masterDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=7iI5Q14IT2qIqXB4dsgRxQ==)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=7iI5Q14IT2qIqXB4dsgRxQ==)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at MagicBox.util.database.Utils.createOracleHikariDataSource(Utils.java:57) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.selectAnyDataSource(DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:34) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig.masterDataSource(TenantDataSourceConfig.java:79) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156.CGLIB$masterDataSource$3(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$22774e9f.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156.masterDataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=7iI5Q14IT2qIqXB4dsgRxQ==)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:870) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:675) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1032) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:90) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:681) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:602) ~[ojdbc8-21.1.0.0.jar:21.1.0.0.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
        at MagicBox.util.database.Utils.createOracleHikariDataSource(Utils.java:57) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.selectAnyDataSource(DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:34) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig.masterDataSource(TenantDataSourceConfig.java:79) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156.CGLIB$masterDataSource$3(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$22774e9f.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at MagicBox.configuration.datasource.multiTenancy.TenantDataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abe3d156.masterDataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
   ...
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler$IOReadTimeoutException: Socket read timed out
 ...
```

Do you have any idea of what is going on with my TLS connection? Any hint to solve the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to implement TLS without key exchange? You can't have *no* key exchange: at the least the server needs to have a trusted certificate chain for the root certificate authority that matches the chain from the client certificate. You can't have a connection without that trust relationship.

Comment: You have this ID `CONNECTION_ID=7iI5Q14IT2qIqXB4dsgRxQ==` on client side reported. The same connection ID should be also logged by the database in one of .trc files. You can also increase logging level in listener.ora

Comment: @pmdba as it reads in Jean De Lavarene "SSL With Oracle JDBC Thin Driver" paper [link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) and at least if I didn't read it wrong, with Diffie-Hellman encryptation method "You do not need to set any “truststore” nor “keystore” in client side. However the cipher suite
must be forced to use Diffie-Hellman anonymous authentication" for cipher purposes. Am I right?

Comment: To include more info, I was worried of that Connection Timeout, so I did a telnet to the host OServerA at port 2484 and big surprise... the communication never happened. So I double checked the firewall realising that the communication block was coming from the router itself, I forgot to add a rule to bypass over 2484 >.<". Now the problem changed to "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)" message is clear, I'll be looking for a cipher suit that fits into the solution for bot server and java connection conf.